# Zend_Form: Database records in HTML table with checkboxes

Tags: php, zend-framework, checkbox, zend-form, dbtable

I am trying to add a HTML multi-column table to a Zend_Form. The table would be populated by data from the database and each row should be preceded by a checkbox, as shown in the ASCII below:

```
+-----+-------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+
|     | Column_1                | Column_2              | Column_3     |
+-----+-------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+
| [x] | Row #1                  | Some data             | more data    |
+-----+-------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+
| [x] | Row #2                  | Some data             | more data    |
+-----+-------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+
| [x] | Row #3                  | Some data             | more data    |
+-----+-------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+
```

The table would handle many-to-many relationships. Would anyone happen to know how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you'll have to remove `DtDd` Decorator, set the `Html` Decorator tag to div and remove the `Label` Decorator.

I suggest you make the form as best you can then work from that, at least give it a go.

In the worst situation you will have to write your own form elements to replicate this HTML.

Comment: I made my own form element and decorator instead, but thanks.

Comment: @Andy, that would be the way to go. I'm trying to make a Zend_Form that adds the correct elements for the datatypes matching the fields, etc, etc, etc. A one stop CRUD solutions perhaps?

Comment: Could you post the custom element and decorator ?