# Zend_Form and Decorator Layout

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, decorator

Is there any way to setup all my Zend_Forms with this ?

```
$this->element->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    'Label',
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'id' => '[MyElementLabel]')));
```

Instead of do that one by one element of my Zend_forms? I mean something like a Form layout

Answer (score 2):

The most concise way to override default decorators is by creating your own set of elements and overriding the `loadDefaultDecorators()` method.

You get `Zend_Form` to load your classes instead of it's own by adding your custom prefix path to it's plugin loader.

Here's some examples from my custom set of form elements

- Form class - https://github.com/philBrown/Tolerable/blob/master/library/Tolerable/Form.php
- Primary element - https://github.com/philBrown/Tolerable/blob/master/library/Tolerable/Form/Element.php
- Custom elements - https://github.com/philBrown/Tolerable/tree/master/library/Tolerable/Form/Element
- Decorators - https://github.com/philBrown/Tolerable/tree/master/library/Tolerable/Form/Decorator

This is a little out of date as I haven't committed recent changes but the stuff you're looking for is applicable (plugin loader, default decorators, etc)

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a way to handle Zend_Forms without dealing with the decorators (a quick and easy approach) check out: [Zend_Form : data table with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028252/zend-form-data-table-with-checkboxes/7031241#7031241)

Ignore the checkbox stuff, the important part is laying out your form the way you want in your view (or in a partial if you want to reuse the form html) so pass the form to your view and call the elements into the html as needed.